# Structuring a React Application

Tags: reactjs

I have a page in my application with two dropdowns - VesselList and KeydateList. VesselList dropdown is filled via an api and then the KeydateList dropdown via another api based on the selected value in VesselList. What is the react way of structuring this? The dropdowns will be used in other pages as well.

I have thought about 2 cases:

1. Have a MainInputBar.js page whose state records the value selected in the VesselList dropdown. VesselList has its own state which gets filled with the value of the api call. I pass a handler to VesselList which updates the state in MainInputBar with the selected value, and then I pass the selected value as props to KeydateList. KeydateList has its own state which is filled with the result of the api call.
2. Have MainInputBar.js handle the entire state - including the values of both the dropdowns, handle the api calls and have the dropdown pages simply render based on props.

Which one of these would be preferable? Or is there some other better way?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the second case because you can call backend APIs in one component (MainInputBar.jsx). Other than that, they isn't much difference, just a preference problem.

**MainInputBar.jsx**

```
construct(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        vessels: [],
        keydates: [],
        selectedVessel: null,
        selectedKeydate: null
    }
    this.changeVessel = this.changeVessel.bind(this)
    this.changeKeydate = this.changeKeydate.bind(this)
}

changeVessel(e) {
    this.setState({
        selectedVessel: e.target.value  
    })
    this.doSthWithTwoDropdownsState()
}

changeKeydate(e) {
    this.setState({
        selectedKeydate: e.target.value
    })
    this.doSthWithTwoDropdownsState()
}

doSthWithTwoDropdownsState() {
    if(this.state.selectedVessel && this.state.selectedKeydate) {
        apiService.callSomething({
            vessel: this.state.selectedVessel,
            keydate: this.state.selectedKeydate
        }).then((resp) => {
            // do something here
        })
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    apiService.fetchVessesls().then(resp => {
        this.setState({
            vessels: resp.vessels
        })
    })
    apiService.fetchKeydates().then(resp => {
        this.setState({
            keydates: resp.keydates
        })
    })
    /*
    * Can be optimized like the following: 
    * 
    * apiService.fetchDropdownData().then(resp => {
    *   this.setState({
    *      keydates: resp.keydates
    *      vessels: resp.vessels
    *   })
    * })
    *
    */
}

render() {
    return (
        <VesselList 
            onChange={this.changeVessel} 
            options={this.state.vessels}
        />
        <KeydateList 
            onChange={this.changeKeydate}
            options={this.sttae.keydates}
        />
    )   
}
```

**VesselList.jsx**

```
render() {
    <div>
        <select onChange={this.props.onChange}>
            {this.props.options.map(option => {
                return (
                    <option value={option.value}>{option.text}</option>
                )
            })}
        </select>
    </div>  
}
```

**KeydateList.jsx**

```
render() {
    <div>
        <select onChange={this.props.onChange}>
            {this.props.options.map(option => {
                return (
                    <option value={option.value}>{option.text}</option>
                )
            })}
        </select>
    </div>      
}
```

For the first case, the code will remain almost the same, except that `fetchVessels` and `fetchKeydates` must be called separately in their components' `componentDidMount`resp. If the backend api cannot be optimized as I showed in the comment, it won't be much difference really.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have a couple of questions. If the performance is similar, and I had to use both the dropdowns for other pages, would the first option not be better? I would not need to implement the apis in those other parent components then, right?  Also, the second dropdown values depend on the first one - the first dropdown's selected value is a parameter for the 2nd api. So, in the second case, as per your code, can that be handled that in componentDidMount()?

Comment: Let me guess, when you select the first dropdown, it should fetch data for second(KeydateList) and update KeydateList, am I right? Are you saying second dropdown values depend on the first one in this context? If this is a case, there won't be much difference. Can show you another example, if you give further detail.

Comment: Also, if the two components have to be in different pages, how can they be dependent? As long as you need MainInputBar, there is not much difference between two ways. If the two components are individual and completely independent of each other, the first way is the answer. But if that's the case, it won't be a question. No brainer.

Comment: You are correct about how the dependency works. MainInputBar contains other elements which will not be needed in those other pages which is why I thought it might make the KeydateList and VesselList components less reusable if they did not have their own state. I thought, on those other pages, I could have different parent components pass props  to these dropdown components. Also, VesselList can be completely independent, but not KeydateList.

Comment: can you please take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60654180/trigger-2-re-renders-on-props-change