# Trigger 2 re-renders on props change

Tags: reactjs

I would like to the list of options to go back to empty on getting new a `vesselname`. Using the below code, updating `optionList` to an empty array inside `componentDidUpdate` does not trigger a re-render. So on selecting a new vessel, the previous keydate remains selected, although if I click the dropdown, I can see it is populated with new values from the api call.

**KeydateDropdown.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import axios from 'axios';    

class KeydateDropdown extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            optionList: []
        };
    };

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        let vesselname = this.props.vesselname;
        if (prevProps.vesselname !== vesselname) {
            let keydateList = [];
            this.setState({
                optionList: keydateList
            });
            axios.get('list-keydates', {
                params: {
                    vesselname: vesselname
                }
            })
                .then((response) => {
                    let data = response.data['intervention'];
                    data.forEach((element) => {
                        keydateList.push({ value: element, label: element });
                    });
                    this.setState({ optionList: keydateList });
                })
        }
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <Select
                isDisabled={this.props.isDisabled}
                onChange={this.props.handleKeydateChange}
                options={this.state.optionList}
                className={styles.dropdown}
            />
        );
    }

}

export default KeydateDropdown;
```

Comment: can you put a log here `if (prevProps.vesselname !== vesselname) {` which will actually determine weather set state is called or not.

Comment: I think you are trying to re-render when prevProps and newProps are not equal. `componentWillReceiveProps` is for this case, but it's deprecated and not considered to be a desirable way. Only if I can see your problem more clearly...

Comment: [Official recommendation to get around this problem](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-controlled-component). I hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [passing a callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to `setState`. I suspect setting state twice in `componentDidUpdate` might be related to it not rendering twice.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps)
```

or

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)
```

Comment: `componentWillUpdate` shouldn't be used anymore.